# An algorithm for finding converse duplicates of ordered pairs

Tags: algorithms, graph

Given an array of ordered pairs of values, what algorithm will find converse duplicates? [Converse meaning the same values, but in the opposite order.]

That is, given [ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,ca,db] is there an efficient way to find ca and db, being the converse duplicates for ac and bd?

The application is simple enough: the ordered pairs are edges in a directed graph and if there is a converse edge then a single double-ended edge is to be drawn rather than one edge in each direction. The values are strings, being node names.

It can be viewed as a lookup in a sparse array. Given coordinates (a,b), check whether (b,a) exists. However, common programming languages do not (appear to) provide sparse 2d arrays.

I have written a solution in ruby using hash-of-hash, but it's about 20 lines of awkward code and an unsatisfying outcome. Writing the same code in a language like C# or Java would be longer. A better solution is sought, in pseudocode or a description (steps) of the algorithm. Either way, I am seeking an answer that describes how to find the solution as well as the benefits and drawbacks of the particular algorithm.

---

I haven't attempted to define 'efficient' or 'better', and performance is not an overriding consideration for a drawing of a few hundred nodes.

The nodes are not sorted, so the default algorithm would be, for each pair, to form the converse and brute-force search the preceding half. A binary search would require a prior sort. A solution based on hash indexing should be much faster.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. So you want to find a pair of pairs of values (x,y) and (z,t) such that z, t are the lexicographical inverse of x and y?

Comment: How fast do you want it to be? simply checking each edge for its converse with a binary search is O(n log n), which is usually considered efficient. So what complexity are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @randomA: No, I want to find all pairs of pairs such as (x,y) and (y,x), and handle them differently (draw double-ended arrow).

Comment: @Frank: See edit.

Comment: Create two hash values from each tuple. First hash is computed from an ordered-tuple hash function; Second hash is computed from the reversed tuple using the same ordered-tuple hash function. (This is actually a quite elementary algorithm design question.)

Comment: @rwong: Why ordered? But yes, I suddenly realise that a suitable tuple hash function (based on object value not identity) and a hash map allows the converse tuple to be looked up very cheaply. That may be the answer.

Comment: Another term for "converse" would be "symmetric", especially when viewing the collection (or graph) as a relation. 2D sparse arrays are also called "sparse matrices"; though they usually aren't part of the standard library, they're often used by graph libraries for adjacency matrices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as written and answered, the question is answerable by unexplained code snippets in arbitrary languages.

Comment: @MichaelT: Full marks for originality: I've never seen that as a close reason before. It was a serious question about an actual problem and I was disappointed at the outcome. I thought it deserved better answers, but is that the fault of the question?

Comment: @david.pfx I'm not sure. I remember looking at the question nearly a year ago and thinking it looked good and could get some good answers. Unfortunately, what you are getting is "here's an implementation in python, here's another one in ruby..." and it appears to be taking on more of an algorithm golf problem nature (with some code) than what I'd really *like* to see from the question.

Comment: @MichaelT That close reason kind of baffles me too, and it feels like dodging the actual problem. I'll start a discussion on meta to work out why this question attracted such golf-y answers and what a more correct solution would be (I suspect editing the question is part of it).

Answer (score 1):

Just collect the pairs in a set.  (In Ruby, it will be a Set of two-element Arrays.)

```
let Set s = {}
for each pair [a,b]
   if s contains [a,b]
      // duplicate, do nothing
   else if s contains [b,a] // converse duplicate
      ...
   else
      add [a,b] to S
```

If you are writing Ruby, it is already capable of using arrays

Comment: We must have different definitions of trivial. I do not see that f() performs any sorting function. I do not see explanations of the xxx-edge() functions. I do not see any output of converse duplicates. In short, I do not see a solution.

Answer (score -2):

This is the code for my ruby implementation. The output is in a format intended for Graphviz.

```
  graph_edges = {}
  fmap.keys.sort.each do |srckey|
    forms = fmap[srckey]
    fsrc = $1 if srckey =~ /---/
    forms.keys.each do |fkey|
      fdest = $1 if fkey =~ /---/
      if fdest
        if graph_edges[fdest] && graph_edges[fdest][fsrc]
          graph_edges[fdest][fsrc] = :both
        else
          graph_edges[fsrc] ||= {}
          graph_edges[fsrc][fdest] ||= :only
        end
      end
    end if fsrc
  end
  fout3.puts "digraph {"
  graph_edges.each do |fsrc,h| 
    h.each_pair do |fdest,dir| 
      dirs = " [dir = both]" if dir == :both
      fout3.puts "  #{fsrc} -> #{fdest}#{dirs};" 
    end
  end
  fout3.puts "}"
```

Hopefully there is something useful here. I shall be working on something better based on a tuple value hash.

Comment: Programmers is [about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour) conceptual questions and answers are [expected to _explain_ things](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer). Throwing code dumps instead of explanation is like copying code from IDE to whiteboard: it may look familiar and even sometimes be understandable, but it feels weird... just weird. [Whiteboard doesn't have compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/839601)

Answer (score -2):

Here's a working solution with decent performance.

```
ordered = lambda x, y: (x, y) if x <= y else (y, x)

def makeArrows(edges):
  """
  input: a sequence of (src, dst) pairs, maybe some reciprocal.
  output: generator yielding (src, dst, is_double_ended) triples.
  """
  undirected_edges = set()
  for src, dst in edges:
    edge = ordered(src, dst)  # both 'ab' and 'ba' become ('a', 'b') here
    if edge in undirected_edges:
      # we found a reciprocal; there can only be one pair like 'ab' + 'ba',
      # so we remove it and output as double-ended
      undirected_edges.remove(edge)
      yield (src, dst, True)
    else:
      # accumulate an edge and wait; a reciprocal might be ahead
      undirected_edges.add(edge)
  # all edges not removed by now are one-ended
  for (src, dst) in undirected_edges:
    yield (src, dst, False)
```

Now we can try it. Since Python strings are sequences, here I short-cut `'ab'` instead of `('a', 'b')`.

```
raw_edges = ['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'ca', 'db']

>>> list(makeArrows(raw_edges))
[('c', 'a', True), ('d', 'b', True), ('b', 'c', False), ('a', 'b', False), ('a', 'd', False)]
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a way...in python

```
ordered = lambda x, y: (x, y) if x <= y else (y, x)

def make_hash(edges):
    edge_hash = {}
    for x,y in edges:
        edge = ordered(x, y)
        edge_hash[edge] = edge_hash.setdefault(edge, 0) + 1
    return edge_hash

edges = ['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'ca', 'db']

for edge, count in make_hash(edges).items():
    print ''.join(edge), 'uni' if count == 1 else 'bi'
```

It creates a dictionary (hash) that is indexed by the sorted order of the edges. If there are two entries, we know it is has a converse duplicate. If only one, it is not. The dictionary is returned and the count of matching (in any order) entries.

Comment: Programmers.SE encourages questions that explain the _why_ behind the _how_.  Your answer would be much stronger if you stated how your suggested algorithm addresses the OP's concerns and how this approach is superior to other approaches.